# How to find command used to implement "Volume Up" shortcut in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, volume-control, notify-osd

In Ubuntu 18.04, there are keyboard shortcuts for "Volume down" and "Volume up", which, on a laptop computer, are usually bound to the media keys (e.g., `XF86AudioRaiseVolume`).

[image: keyboard-shortcuts]

When I press the shortcut, the volume increases and an OSD notification indicates the new volume level.

[image: osd-notification]

**Question** How can I find out what command is being run by GNOME to implement "Volume up" and "Volume down", i.e.,  the command which increases the volume and shows the volume pop-up? I can write `xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume` in the terminal to simulate the behavior, but that still doesn't tell me what commands are being run.  Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: It's possible this behavior is hard-coded in in the `gnome-settings-daemon`: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/gsd-media-keys-manager.c

Comment: The command to change the volume and the command to display the popup could be different. Which are you trying to implement?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm trying to implement the combination of the two commands, i.e., the sequence of commands that is run when executing `xdotool key XF86AudioLowerVolume`.